# Custom BehaviorExtensionElement in WCF instancing rules

Tags: .net, wcf

Is behavior of creating instances of BehaviorExtensionElement documented? How much instances of BehaviorExtensionElement can WCF create for an each service? Just one per service or one for an each instance of service class?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any documentation on how the internals of the BehaviorExtensionElement are implemented but I believe you only have one per service configuration. It does allow you to add many different types (service, endpoint, operation, contract) of behaviors to a service. You've probably already seen the none to helpful [documentation here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.behaviorextensionelement.aspx) A better article is [here also on MSDN but with examples.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730137.aspx)